# Grid Layout - Square Photo Wall

Tags: css, css-grid, photo

I tried to rebuild this Square Grid: [how-to-create-a-flexible-square-grid-with-css-grid-layout](https://medium.com/cloudaper/how-to-create-a-flexible-square-grid-with-css-grid-layout-ea48baf038f3)

It works until I put images into the grid elements: [Photo wall](https://jsr-hersbruck.de/visitenkarte/photo.html)

```css
.square-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.square-container::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.square-container > *:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

/* Just to make the grid visible */

.square-container > * {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.square-container > *:focus,
.square-container > *:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.square-container img
    { object-fit: contain; width:100%; height:auto; padding:0; margin:0; }
```

How can I fit the img-elements into the whole size of the grid-element?

```css
.square-container img { 
object-fit: cover; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;  
}
```

creates a rectangle. A fixed `grid-auto-rows: 15rem` creates a near-square but then I can abstain from the pseudo element.

Comment: Check your link, it's your local file url

Comment: Thanks - corrected it -Found the solution in an older post:  .square-container > a {

  position: relative;
}

.square-container > *:focus,
.square-container img { 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  lefT:0;
  object-fit: cover; 
  width:100%; 
  height: 100%;  }

Comment: Great! but i don't think you need this part `.square-container > *:focus`, do you?